# UK Visitor Visa - dependent related question

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm planning to apply for UK Visitor visa.
I'm living with my mother, my younger brother (student: he is doing his graduation), my wife and two kids. I'm finanical supporting all members. My married sister also finanical support in my younger brother she is housewife.

My question is should i add my mother and brother in my dependents(i know form separately ask for parents details)?
As per my understanding my dependents are my wife and two kids (only one of them is school going).

How i can present this in online form or UK visa in better way. Showing all members as my dependent will reduce my visa chances?

Answer (score 3):

The Visit guide to the process for making a decision on a visit visa application published by the Home Office says:

“You must also take into account any ongoing financial commitments the applicant has in their country of residence such as rent/ mortgage payments and any dependants who they support financially, including those who are not travelling with them.
Their income or savings, minus their financial commitments, must be sufficient to meet the likely costs they will incur in the UK and be reasonable expenditure in light of their financial situation.”

For the purposes of your application, your dependents are **all** the people whom you support financially. You must tell the truth and declare all of them in your application. Doing so will not harm your chances of success providing your overall financial circumstances are healthy and your intended spend on your planned visit to the UK is proportionate to your income and savings. The existence of family member dependents in your home country is typically thought of as a *tie* - something that is likely to compel you to leave the UK at the end of your visit - so could count in your favour.

Source: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf#page24

Comment: My savings in my main account are 5658 GBP. Joint account with wife 1300 GBP. Monthly expenses are 548 GBP covering all dependents in my home country. Estimated cost for 14 days will be 1700 GBP as per my calculations.
 5658 - (1700 + 548) = 3410 (Remaining after trip)
also i have Provident Fund in my company 4788 GBP i will attach document for this as well - idont know this can be consider as saving or not.  I rarely use Joint account so for that account i am planning to attach 3 months statement but for main account i will attach 6 mnoths statement.I really appreciate @Traveller answer.

Comment: @Shoaib Rashid If you’ve not done so already, it may help you to read this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: No funds parking is done by me.Yup i have arleady visted this nice article. I am consistently saving my 40-50% earnings each month. Balance never went negative or dipped.

Comment: @Shoaib Rashid Your Provident Fund monies should count towards V 4.2.(e) as proof of sufficient funds provided the account allows the monies to be accessed immediately.